# How to set what user types in textarea as a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so I have a HTML textarea. I want what the user types in it to be displayed on the screen and also stored in a variable. I have the displaying part but I can't figure out how to store it as a a variable.

The html

```
 <textarea id="input" maxlength="50" name="Text" placeholder="Max. 50 characters"></textarea>
```

The javascript

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#text').html($(this).val());
        var yourText = this.val();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should use `change` or `input` instead of `keyup`. Not everyone uses a keyboard!

Second, only jQuery objects have a `val()` method. Using `this` you are referring to the `<textarea>` element which does not:

```
$('#input').on("input", function() {
    var yourText = $(this).val(); // Only jQuery objects have a .val()
    $('#text').html(yourText); // Pass your variable in here
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wva2knd/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#text').html($(this).val());
        var yourText = this.val();
    });
```

Should be

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#input').html($(this).val());
        var yourText = $(this).val();
    });
```

You gave #text as an id, but the id name of the input is #input

Answer (score 1):

You forget the javascript closure `$` on this. Use the code below

```
<textarea id="input" maxlength="50" name="Text" placeholder="Max. 50 characters"></textarea>
<div id="text1"></div>
<script>
$('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#text').html($(this).val());
        var yourText = $(this).val();
    $("#text1").html(yourText);
    });
</script>
```

JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/7tfs93o2/

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `var yourText = this.val();` but since you are using JQuery there, `.val()` is a JQuery method, `this` should also be wrapped with the JQuery layer like this:

`var yourText = $(this).val();`